# Find out the difference in days between two dates taken from two columns in a database and place that difference into a variable for use in php

Tags: php, mysql

I thought mysql could calculate it so I made a variable called `$sqlDateDiff`.

`$servername = "localhost";$username = "root";$password = "";$dbname = "maplibrary";`

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
$sqlDateDiff = "SELECT DATEDIFF(BorrowedDate, ReturnedDate) 
                FROM bookstakenout WHERE BorrowNumberID = $bnid" ;

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDateDiff);
```

Then I would like to use `$result` to create a nested `if` statement. How can I store the difference in a variable to use in a `if` statement.

In the `bookstakenout` table the `ReturnedDate/BorrowedDate` are both yyyy-mm-dd

> Blockquote

Comment: Look at `$sqlDateDiff` and `($conn, $sqltheDateDiff)`, what doesn't match here? Plus, you can't just "echo" `$result` like that. You need to loop over results.

Comment: so now you edited. so what's the problem now? I don't see where you're looping over results or if you connected successfully, you're going to need to tell us what's NOT happening here. I can't hang around this question any much longer; not without knowing exactly which animal(s) were dealing with here.

Comment: Sorry, it has changed a few times while trying to get it to work in my program. I have fixed that now. Can you please tell me how I can store the result? The `$sqlDateDiff` has a where clause that can only ever match a single entry on the table.

Comment: The connection to the database is fine and working correctly.

Comment: I don't know how to loop the result into a variable that I can use.

Comment: I guess I'l keep hitting refresh and hope someone saves me...

Comment: My knight in coding armor <3

Comment: Check out the documentation for [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and the examples there. You can use it basically word for word.

Answer (score 0):

Query: DATEDIFF(datepart,start date,end date ) as DIFFDATE